# Smoothly pause a repeating UIView block animation on alpha before another animation

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewanimation

I've read many Stack Overflow questions in search of a solution for this, but I can't find one that addresses this particular issue in a way that works in iOS 13.

I have a label that I want to pulse repeatedly (like a slow, fading blink) once my view controller loads.

When it's time to transition away from the view, at the push of a button, I want to stop the pulsing at whatever alpha the pulsing label currently has, and then fade it out from there along with other UI elements.

In the past, I would have used a `UIViewPropertyAnimator` for this repeating animation, and then paused the animation once the button is tapped, but as of iOS 13 `UIView.setAnimationRepeatCount(.greatestFiniteMagnitude)` and `UIView.setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses(true)` are deprecated, which (I think) makes it impossible to build my pulse animation with a property animator.

Here is my example code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private lazy var pulsingLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "I am pulsing"
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    private lazy var stopButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("Stop Pulsing",
                        for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self,
                         action: #selector(fadeEverythingOut),
                         for: .touchUpInside)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return button
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(pulsingLabel)
        view.addSubview(stopButton)

        pulsingLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        pulsingLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

        stopButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        stopButton.firstBaselineAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingBelow: pulsingLabel.lastBaselineAnchor,
                                                  multiplier: 4).isActive = true

        startRepeatingAnimation()
    }

    private func startRepeatingAnimation() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1,
                       delay: 0,
                       options: [.repeat, .autoreverse, .curveEaseInOut],
                       animations: {
            self.pulsingLabel.alpha = 0
        })
    }

    @objc
    private func fadeEverythingOut() {

        pulsingLabel.layer.removeAllAnimations()

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0,
                       animations: {
            self.pulsingLabel.alpha = 0
        })
    }
}
```

In this example, I'm calling `pulsingLabel.layer.removeAllAnimations()` to stop the animation, but this is not an acceptable solution because the label just immediately disappears when it's called.

I've also tried some weird stuff like sandwiching that line between `UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)` and `UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)`, but that didn't work.

I also tried saving the alpha of `pulsingLabel` right before calling `pulsingLabel.layer.removeAllAnimations()` and then setting it again right after, but I always get a value of `0` for `pulsingLabel.alpha`.

Am I missing something here by abandoning `UIViewPropertyAnimator`, where I would still be able to get it to repeat, even with the deprecated functions on `UIView`? Or maybe I need to be calling `.layer.removeAllAnimations()` on a different layer or differently somehow?

Any ideas would be much appreciated, as I care quite a bit about getting these fine details right in my app!

Comment: You cannot. UiView animation block applies the property instantly, but the iOS simply animates the change. What you need is to run via a background timer thread of somesort.

Comment: @GeneCode OK, thanks. Can you provide an answer that uses your approach of "run via a background timer thread of somesort"?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see that you were looking for swift answer, but I only know ObjC right now. So here is the solution by timer (though in ObjC sorry):

In viewdidload:

```
    self.angle = 0;
    self.myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(update) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

`angle` is CGFloat to store current value to calculate the alpha by cosine function in update method:

```
-(void)update {
    self.angle += M_PI/36.0;
    if (self.angle > M_PI) self.angle = 0.0;
    CGFloat val = (1 + cos(self.angle)) / 2.0;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.myLabel.alpha = val;
    });
}
```

You can adjust the value 36.0 to make the fade in/out slower or faster. `val` will give a swing value between 0 and 1 back and forth, as `angle` increases. Then using GCD we set the label alpha as needed in real time. When a button is pressed to move to another viewcontroller (as per your requirement), you only need to stop the timer by invalidating it, and the label will remain at whatever alpha is was set.

```
[self.myTimer invalidate];
self.myTimer = nil;
// CGFloat currentAlpha = self.myLabel.alpha;
```

From here, you can do other thing with label alpha.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to remove all animations and reset alpha inside a `UIView.transition` block. This will smoothly transition the current view state to the final state using a cross-dissolve animation, hence achieving a smooth transition:

```
UIView.transition(with: stackView, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionCrossDissolve) {
    self.pulsingLabel.layer.removeAllAnimations()
    self.pulsingLabel.alpha = 1
}
```